# M68000 Assembly, how do I loop a subtraction

Tags: assembly, 68000

I want to make a subtraction loop. I am tasked with finding out the number of $100 bills in a sum. For example, user enters $950. There is 9 one hundred dollar bills in that. What I first did was store the user input in date register 1, and compare it to 100.

```
cmpi.w      #100,D1
```

I want to basically do "if D1 is less than 100, subtract another 100". How can I achieve this loop? I would like to use the branch greater than and less than instructions but am not sure how.

Comment: you mean "if D1 is less than 100, **do NOT subtract** another 100"? .. check some tutorial, this one looks overly verbose to me, so it may be good for you: http://mrjester.hapisan.com/04_MC68/Index.html (part 6 and 7 deals with signed/unsigned integer branches) ... generally you create piece of code, which does subtract and  loops, and other piece of code which does not subtract and finishes the stuff, put some label ahead of them (label is like bookmark, marking certain memory address), then you use branch instruction to jump to certain memory location (label) when some condition is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal algorithm would be to divide by 100. The M68K `DIVU`/`DIVS` instructions provide the result and the remainder at the same time:

```
MOVE #950,D1
DIVU #100,D1
```

Will leave `0x00320009` in the D1 register, i.e., 0x9 (9) as the result and 0x32 (50) as the remainder.

If you really want a loop, take a look at the following code (assembles and runs on EASy68K (http://www.easy68k.com/)). This is very standard assembly code, and loops on other architectures look very similar. (In fact, this is the first time I've ever written M68K assembly code.)

```
START:
    MOVE #950,D1
Loop:
    CMP #100,D1
    BPL OverEqual100
    BRA Under100
OverEqual100:
    SUB #100,D1
    ADD #1,D0
    BRA Loop
Under100:
    SIMHALT
```

(Also see the comments attached to this answer.)

Comment: You need `>=` branch, or `<` branch at the beginning of loop, otherwise your loop will count it wrong for input like `100`.  ... uhm `bpl` actually **is** `>=`, so the code is ok. (the mnemonics are inaccurate, as zero is not positive value in math .. and your label is inaccurate too, should be `OverEqual100:` and `Under100:`)

Comment: And it can be simplified by using only single `bmi Under100` instead of two `bpl + bra` jumps.

Comment: Fixed the labels. Thanks!